# How to configure a kubernetes bare-metal ingress controller to listen to port 80?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, cloud-bare-metal

I have a kubernetes setup with 1 master and 1 slave, hosted on DigitalOcean Droplets.
For exposing my services I want to use Ingresses.

As I have a bare metal install, I have to configure my own ingress controller.
**How do I get it to listen to port 443 or 80 instead of the 30000-32767 range?**

For setting up the ingress controller I used this guide: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/

My controller service looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
```

And now obviously, because the NodePort range is 30000-32767, this controller doesn't get mapped to port 80 or 443:

```
➜ kubectl get services --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE       NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx          NodePort    10.103.166.230   <none>        80:30907/TCP,443:30653/TCP   21m
```

Comment: Well, who are the _consumers_ of that `Service`? Are your users going to all have access to `:80` and `:443` of the `Nodes` in your cluster, or do you have a firewall that seals off access away from the actual `Nodes`? That said, the way I solved that problem was to use `hostNetwork: true` with a `DaemonSet`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with @Matthew L Daniel, if you don't consider to use external load balancer, the best option would be sharing host network interface with `ingress-nginx` Pod by enabling `hostNetwork` option in the Pods' spec:

```
template:
  spec:
    hostNetwork: true
```

Thus, NGINX Ingress controller can bind ports 80 and 443 directly to Kubernetes nodes, without mapping special proxy ports (30000-32767) to the nested services. Find more information [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#via-the-host-network).

Answer (score 0):

You can’t bind ingress service to port 80. You can run HAProxy  on the host and redirect port 80,443 request Ingress service port number.